# SpringBoot does not run unit tests when added into dependencyManagement

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, junit5

My project is supposed to be inherited from a custom parent and at the same time use `Spring Boot`.
The standard solution for that is using `<dependencyManagement>` section as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency-management-custom-parent).

The problem is when a `Spring Boot` dependency is added into the section, maven does not see any unit tests (Test runs = 0). I reproduced that with artifacts `spring-boot-dependencies` and `spring-boot-starter`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create a maven project with one unit test `SampleTest` and the following pom.
2. run `mvn test`.
3. see that `SampleTest` has run and failed
4. uncomment the block in `<dependencyManagement>` to import `Spring Boot`
5. run `mvn test`
6. see no tests have run and the build is succesfull.

I had similar problems with older versions of `surefire`, which could not find `JUnit5` tests in a similar manner. But the effective pom shows that in this case plugins' versions are correctly set to `3.0.0-M4` and not overridden by SpringBoot.

**Could you help me fix the problem with running tests and properly apply `Spring Boot` in this case?**

---

`src/test/java/org/example/SampleTest.java`

```
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

class SampleTest{
    @Test
    void test(){
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, 1);
    }
}
```

---

`pom.xml`

> The following sample does not have a parent: I've just copied plugins
>   and dependencies from that to keep it concise.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-import</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <!-- when this block is uncommented no unit tests are found in the project-->

    <!--
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    -->
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <version.java>11</version.java>
        <version.junit.jupiter>5.6.0</version.junit.jupiter>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>${version.java}</compilerVersion>
                    <release>${version.java}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit.jupiter}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: And it should because? Adding something to the `dependencyManagement` section doesn't add the dependencies to your project.

Comment: @M.Denium I do not expect to automatically have ``spring-boot-starter-webflux`` or something, because of uncommenting the block in `depsManagement`. I expect it not to break what already works and have just found the shortest example how to reproduce the problem. 
Actually your comment is so laconic that I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate on that? Do you have any clue why project fails to find the tests?

Comment: I missed the fact you already had the junit dependency and you wouldn't be the first (nor the last) to misunderstand the `dependencyManagement` section.

Comment: The `dependencyManagement` imports the Spring Boot managed dependencies and changes some of the dependency versions of the `junit-jupiter-engine`, because they are probably explicitly defined. They are downgraded to 5.5.2 which are probably incompatible. If you run a maven dependency check with transitives you will see (if you compare the befopre and after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the `spring-boot-dependencies` dependencies changes the transitive dependencies of the `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency.

The output of `mvn dependency:tree` will show this.

**Before**

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ spring-boot-import ---
[INFO] org.example:spring-boot-import:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.0:test
[INFO]    \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.0:test
```

**After**

```
[INFO] org.example:spring-boot-import:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
```

As you can see the `junit-platform-engine` and friends changed from **1.6.0** to **1.5.2** and the API from **5.6.0** to **5.5.2**. As those jars are incompatible versions your tests won't run anymore.

To fix you can do 1 of the following

1. Add all additional, transitive, dependencies with an explicit version
2. Add the `junit-bom` as well to the `dependencyManagement` section before the Spring Boot one, to force the versions
3. Downgrade to JUnit 5.5.2 to align with the Spring Boot managed version

Comment: Man, you're brilliant. I knew that spring-boot overrides something, but I've suspected plugins and did not notice that jupiter mess.

Comment: @khmarbaise That isn't what he is saying, he was thinking that the Spring Boot dependency was overriding plugin versions.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using `Spring Boot 2.x` then by default it supports `JUnit 5` and all the test cases written in `JUnit 4` will not be read while building the project or while executing `mvn` test.
To fix it, use the below snippet in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <!-- Use the older JUnit 4 provider -->
            <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Note: using the above will skip your `JUnit 5` test cases.

Comment: I had same problem. It resolved when I followed @shanky442 's suggestion. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The other solution is simply to define the import for junit jupiter before spring boot. That solves the issue also.

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>    
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```